# Why the original Linked List is getting lost after passing as a argument in reverse function

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, reverse, palindrome

When I am trying to reverse the original Linked List, it gets lost after the function call. Why is it so?

```
Node *reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *prevNode = NULL, *currNode = head;
    while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        Node *nextNode = currNode->next;
        currNode->next = prevNode;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }
    return prevNode;
}

bool isPalindrome(Node *head)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *reversedList = reverse(temp);
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->data != reversedList->data)
        {
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        reversedList = reversedList->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

// https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/

Comment: "it gets lost" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Original Linked List i.e. Head, is lost and contains only 1 node

Comment: You are performing destructive operations on the original linked list by resetting the `next` pointers. If you want to preserve the original linked list, you'll have to create a brand new linked list and make sure that the values of the nodes are in reverse order.

Comment: Note: If you use a doubly linked list you can start at both ends of the list and walk the comparison (If first and last are the same, move first forward one node and last back one node and test again. If not the same, return false) to the center rather than having to waste time and resources reversing the list and then comparing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

The original linked list is lost because the reverse function modifies it. To check for a palindrome without losing the original list, make a deep copy of the list before reversing it. Then, compare the original list with the reversed deep copy.
Try this:

```
Node *deepCopy(Node *head) {
    Node *newHead = NULL, *tail = NULL;

    while (head != NULL) {
        Node *newNode = new Node(head->data);
        if (newHead == NULL) {
            newHead = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }

    return newHead;
}

bool isPalindrome(Node *head) {
    Node *original = head;
    Node *reversed = reverse(deepCopy(head));

    while (original != NULL && reversed != NULL) {
        if (original->data != reversed->data) {
            return false;
        }
        original = original->next;
        reversed = reversed->next;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your `isPalindrome()` is leaking the deep-copied list, you need to `delete` the copied nodes when you are done comparing them. Also, you can simplify your `deepCopy()` by using a `Node**` instead of `tail`, eg: `Node *deepCopy(Node *head) { Node *newHead = NULL, **newNode = &newHead; while (head) { *newNode = new Node(head->data); newNode = &((*newNode)->next); head = head->next; } return newHead; }`